# How to breakdown time policy life period by beginning and end of the months

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services

[Picture. Need to be like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6akpg.png)

I need to break down each policy life period by months. From the beginning of the policy till the end of that month, then from the beginning till the end of the next month and for each of this time period need to calculate the number of days, so then I can calculate earned premium for each policy.

Please see the picture what do I need to achieve.

```
[DECLARE @EarnedToDate datetime ='2016-06-30'
;WITH  Cte_Policies AS 
        (
        SELECT 
            PolicyNumber
            ,TransactionEffectiveDate
            ,TransactionExpirationDate 
            ,WrittenPremium
            ,DATEDIFF(DAY,TransactionEffectiveDate,TransactionExpirationDate) AS TotalDays 
            ,CASE 
                WHEN TransactionEffectiveDate> @EarnedToDate    THEN 0       --Policy not yet in effect 
                WHEN TransactionExpirationDate< @EarnedToDate   THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,TransactionEffectiveDate,TransactionExpirationDate) 
                ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,TransactionEffectiveDate,@EarnedToDate)
            END AS EarnedDays
            ,CASE 
                WHEN TransactionEffectiveDate > @EarnedToDate THEN DATEDIFF(DAY,TransactionEffectiveDate,TransactionExpirationDate) 
                WHEN TransactionExpirationDate < @EarnedToDate THEN 0 -- Policy completed 
                ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,@EarnedToDate,TransactionExpirationDate)
            END AS UnearnedDays         
        FROM ##TempTable1
        )
SELECT PolicyNumber,
        TransactionEffectiveDate as TransactionEffectiveDate,
        TransactionExpirationDate as TransactionExpirationDate
        --WrittenPremium/TotalDays AS DayPremium,
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN EarnedDays   = 0 THEN 0 ELSE WrittenPremium/TotalDays * EarnedDays END) AS EarnedPremium
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN UnearnedDays = 0 THEN 0 ELSE WrittenPremium/TotalDays * UnearnedDays END) AS UnearnedPremium

FROM 
    Cte_Policies where PolicyNumber ='PACA1000238-02'
GROUP BY 
        TransactionEffectiveDate 
        ,TransactionExpirationDate 
        --,WrittenPremium/TotalDays
        ,PolicyNumber][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My original snippet answered your question on Twitter, but the following code snippet takes the first one a bit further and provides exactly the result set specified on your question here on StackOverflow...

```
; WITH Earned_to_date AS (
   SELECT Cast('2016-07-01' AS DATE) AS Earned_to_date
), policy_data AS (
    SELECT
        policy_number
,       Cast(text_Effective  AS DATE) AS TransactionEffectiveDate
,       Cast(text_Expiration AS DATE) AS TransactionExpirationDate
,       policy_premium
        FROM (VALUES
            ('p1', '1993-01-01', '1994-12-31', 940.00)
,           ('p3', '2011-12-01', '2012-05-31', 485.00)
,           ('p5', '2011-12-16', '2012-05-15', 485.00)
,           ('p7', '2015-12-16', '2016-11-15', 485.00)
            ) AS z (policy_number, text_Effective
,                text_Expiration, policy_premium)
), digits AS (
SELECT digit
   FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4)
,      (5), (6), (7), (8), (9)) AS z2 (digit)
), numbers AS (
SELECT 1000 * d4.digit + 100 * d3.digit + 10 * d2.digit + d1.digit AS number
    FROM digits AS d1
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d2
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d3
    CROSS JOIN digits AS d4
), calendar AS (
SELECT
    DateAdd(month, number, '1753-01-01') AS month_of
,   DateAdd(month, number, '1753-02-01') AS month_after
    FROM numbers
), policy_dates AS (
SELECT
    policy_number
,   CASE
        WHEN month_of < TransactionEffectiveDate THEN TransactionEffectiveDate
        ELSE month_of
    END AS StartRiskMonth
,   CASE
       WHEN TransactionExpirationDate < month_after THEN TransactionExpirationDate
       WHEN Earned_to_date.Earned_to_date < month_after THEN Earned_to_date
       ELSE month_after
    END AS EndRiskMonth
,   DateDiff(day, TransactionEffectiveDate, TransactionExpirationDate) AS policy_days
,   policy_premium
    FROM policy_data
    JOIN calendar
        ON (policy_data.TransactionEffectiveDate < calendar.month_after
        AND calendar.month_of < policy_data.TransactionExpirationDate)
    CROSS JOIN Earned_to_date
    WHERE  month_of < Earned_to_date
)
SELECT policy_number, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth
,   DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) AS DaysInMonth
,   policy_premium * DateDiff(day, StartRiskMonth, EndRiskMonth) / policy_days
    FROM policy_dates
    ORDER BY policy_number, StartRiskMonth
```

Answer (score 0):

As I thought from your tweet, this is pretty simple to code but it takes a bit of work to understand.

```
WITH raw_data AS (
    SELECT
        Cast(text_TransactionEffectiveDate AS DATE) AS TransactionEffectiveDate
,       Cast(text_TransactionExpirationDate AS DATE) AS TransactionExpirationDate
        FROM (VALUES
            ('1953-01-15', '1992-02-23')
,           ('2012-08-12', '2012-08-26')
            ) AS z (text_TransactionEffectiveDate, text_TransactionExpirationDate )
), policy_dates AS (
SELECT
    raw_data.*
,   DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, '1753-01-01', TransactionEffectiveDate), '1753-01-01') AS Policy_Start
,   DateAdd(month, DateDiff(month, '1753-01-01', TransactionExpirationDate), '1753-02-01') AS Policy_Expired
    FROM raw_data
)
SELECT DateDiff(day, Policy_start, Policy_Expired) AS Policy_days, *
   FROM policy_dates
```

This is a computation that is common in the insurance field. The trick lies in computing the beginning of the Effective Month, and the beginning of the expiration month (after the policy has ended). The trick is that at one point a month later than the others (1753-02-01) is used.

-PatP

Answer (score 0):

Add a CTE or two that breaks the policy effective and expiration dates into distinct months, then re-use your existing code/CTE

Be sure to review all boundary conditions for EarnedDays and UnearnedDays and make sure they line up with your business rules

```
DECLARE @EarnedToDate DATETIME 
SET @EarnedToDate = '2016-06-30'

DECLARE @tblPolicies TABLE
(
    PolicyNumber VARCHAR(100)
    , PolicyEffectiveDate DATETIME
    , PolicyExpirationDate DATETIME 
    , WP MONEY  --WrittenPremium
) 

DECLARE @tblPolicyMonths TABLE
(
    PolicyNumber VARCHAR(100),
    MonthStart DATETIME,
    MonthEnd DATETIME
)

DECLARE @CurPos INT
SET @CurPos = 1
WHILE @CurPos < 4000
    BEGIN
        --Create a bunch of policies
        INSERT INTO @tblPolicies
            SELECT 'P' + CONVERT(varchar, @CurPos), DATEADD(d, @CurPos,     GETDATE()), DATEADD(YY, 1, DATEADD(d, @CurPos, GETDATE())), @CurPos

        SET @CurPos = @CurPos + 1
    END

DECLARE @LastPolicyDate DATETIME
SET @LastPolicyDate = (SELECT MAX(PolicyExpirationDate) FROM @tblPolicies)

;WITH Cte_All_Dates AS
(
    SELECT MIN(PolicyEffectiveDate) DateValue
        FROM @tblPolicies
       UNION ALL
       SELECT DateValue + 1
       FROM    Cte_All_Dates 
       WHERE   DateValue + 1 < = @LastPolicyDate
)
INSERT INTO @tblPolicyMonths
    SELECT P.PolicyNumber   
        ,MIN(DateValue)
        ,MAX(DateValue)
        FROM Cte_All_Dates PD
            INNER JOIN @tblPolicies P
                ON CONVERT(DATE, PD.DateValue) BETWEEN P.PolicyEffectiveDate    AND P.PolicyExpirationDate
        GROUP BY P.PolicyNumber
            , DATEPART(MM, DateValue)
            , DATEPART(YY, DateValue)
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);

SELECT 
        P.PolicyNumber
        ,CONVERT(DATE, MonthStart) As StartRiskMonth
        ,CONVERT(DATE, MonthEnd) AS EndRiskMonth
        ,WP as WrittenPremium
        ,DATEDIFF(DAY,MonthStart,MonthEnd)+1 AS TotalDays 
        ,CASE 
            WHEN MonthStart > @EarnedToDate THEN 0       --Policy not yet in     effect 
            WHEN MonthEnd < @EarnedToDate THEN     DATEDIFF(DAY,MonthStart,MonthEnd)+1 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,MonthStart,@EarnedToDate)+1
        END AS EarnedDays
        ,CASE 
            WHEN MonthStart > @EarnedToDate THEN     DATEDIFF(DAY,MonthStart,MonthEnd)+1
            WHEN MonthEnd < @EarnedToDate THEN 0 -- Policy completed 
            ELSE DATEDIFF(DAY,@EarnedToDate,MonthEnd)
        END AS UnearnedDays
        , @EarnedToDate AS 'EarnedToDate'
    FROM @tblPolicyMonths PM
        INNER JOIN @tblPolicies P
            ON PM.PolicyNumber = P.PolicyNumber
    ORDER BY PolicyNumber, MonthStart, MonthEnd
```